# How to Filter Contacts using SimpleCursorAdapter and ListView

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to add a **Search Contact** feature in my app.
Everything is working fine but the search contact function is not working.
I trying to implement this feature for 2 days but i don't where i am doing mistake. If anybody can figured out the mistake please write the answer.

```
private void getContactResults () {
        //TODO get contacts code here
        Toast.makeText(this, "Getting contacts ....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        final String phoneNumber = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
        final String phoneName = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
        final String phoneID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;

        final String[] ContactsList = {phoneName, phoneNumber, phoneID};


       final int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
        final SimpleCursorAdapter ArrayAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, ContactsList, to);
        li.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
        li.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
       new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((ContactsList)));

       // Filter contacts by search
       li.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       ArrayAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
           @Override
           public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
               Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
               return cur;
           }
       });


       EditText queryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
       queryText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
               // This is the filter in action
               ArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
               // Don't forget to notify the adapter
               ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
               // This is the filter in action
               ArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
               // Don't forget to notify the adapter
               ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ArrayAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
       @Override
       public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
           Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
           return cur;
       }
   });
```

The error is in the code above. It doesn't look like you are using the `constraint` value

It should be like the

```
  ArrayAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
       @Override
       public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
           Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, new String[]{constraint}, null);
           return cur;
       }
   });
```

I would also advise not using null, as per the android documentation due to performance issue that can arise.

```
 * @param projection A list of which columns to return. Passing null will
 *         return all columns, which is inefficient.
```

Comment: new String[]{constraint} >>>Incompatible types, required java.lang.String, Found java.lang.CharSequence

Comment: I added  String mconstraints = String.valueOf(constraint); and then Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, new String[]{mconstraint}, null);
           return cur; but still not working.